# Unknown error: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read

Tags: angular-cli

Getting this error while running any of the angular command. Even with `ng -v`.
Tried some steps from web but everything is in vain. Node v14.15.3, NPM 6.14.10, Angular cli v11.0.5.

Reinstalled node, cleared npm cache, reinstall global angular cli and still on the same page.

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1BXp.png)

Comment: What's your node version, try to install the correct version of node. https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3

Comment: v14.15.3 node, 6.14.10 npm, 11.0.5 angular cli. All are latest now